# Is it possible to cancel a terraform installation programmatically?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm configuring an AWS environment using terraform, but it needs to fail if a named Docker image is not available on AWS, but I'm not sure if that's possible with terraform, e.g.

```
if (object.exists) then
    continue;
else
    fail("Object not available - aborting install")
```

I know a value can be set with a ternary operator, i.e. `variable = (condition) ? true : false` but that's not what I need

Is it possible?

Comment: If a data source doesn't return a result then it will error. If there's not a data source to look it up you could use the external data source and return an error if the Docker image isn't available. As this happens during the planning stage this will prevent an apply from happening. Would that be enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to fail the install, but you simply need to fail the `plan` phase of your terraform deployment. You can easily achieve that e.g. by using a `data source` that tries to access the docker image and simply fails if the resource is not found. At that point terraform will tell you the plan failed and not continue / allow you to roll out any deployment.

If the docker image is hosted on ECR you can use the [`aws_ecr_image`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ecr_image) data source.